# Tesseract 3.05 mac and android giving different results

Tags: android, macos, tesseract

I am using tesseract in my android application. For some reason, the result returned from tesseract in my mac is different to the result returned from the android application, even with the same image. I am using tesseract 3.05 in my mac and tess-two library, which also uses tesseract 3.05 and the language is english, both are using the eng.traineddata. Is there any particular reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot point to any sources, but I remember having read that Tesseract has a cutoff of how much time it will spend on a given portion of the image. This is to prevent it from taking too much time. So on devices with less CPU, the recognition might degrade instead of becoming slower.

Android has less CPU power, so this cut-off is reached sooner.